# post to user wall from facebook tab

Tags: facebook, permissions, tabs

How can i prompt a user for stream publish and email permissions from a facebook tab? Everything i have found will not let me redirect back to either the current page i have loaded in the iframe or the facebook tab url. Everything I have tried has given me this general Facebook error.

One thing to note is I am not requesting the permissions from the intitial page that is loaded in the tabs iframe. I have a form being filled out and submitted which redirects the iframe to another page, on this second page is where i need to request the permissions. The reason for this is i want the form filled out before possibly scaring the user away because they do not want to allow permissions.

It may be simpler if i can pop up the post to your wall box and have the user click the submit button. This way does not require permissions in advance correct? What would be the code to do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [Feed dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }

        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works well within a page tab.

Comment: I only have to initialize the FB class once per page correct? In other words I already have this on the page
FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});
So i can leave that off of the dialog code correct? Or do I have to include that each time to initialize a new one?

Comment: I finally figured out where the problem was. Before the new changes when you created an app you just created the app. Now you have the option of app, tab, website, android, etc..

If yopu only choose the Tab setting you will get errors using any of the FB API's. You must also choose the app setting.